# Rolling a fair die

Tags: dice

If I roll a die three times, how do you calculate the probability that at least 2 die rolls are less than four?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dice probability - amount of "hits" in a pool](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102962/dice-probability-amount-of-hits-in-a-pool)

Answer (score 1):

Each toss of a die is independent of one another and uniformly distributed. Denote the number shown on each die $X_i$ for $i=1,2,3$. Then $P(X_i \leq 3) = 3/6 = 1/2$. Let this probability represent the probability of "success" (with respect to a Bernoulli trial). Then the probability of achieving two successes in three trials is found through the binomial distribution. Let $Y_i = I(X_i \leq 3)$. Then $Y_1 + Y_2 + Y_3 \sim Binomial(3, p=1/2)$. Thus,
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(Y_1 + Y_2 + Y_3 \geq 2) &= \binom{3}{2}(1/2)^{2}(1/2)^{3-2} + (1/2)^3 \\
&=  1/2
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: It's a good explanation, but usually "less than 4" is interpreted as being equal to 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I overlooked that. Made the edit.

Answer (score 0):

$1-\text{"all dices show 4 or more"} - \text{"exact two dices shows 4 or more"}$
$=1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3}-\left(\begin{array}{c}3\\2\end{array}\right)\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}=\frac{1}{2}$